# Disconnecting a ZIF connector

Tags: connector

I'm trying to disconnect a ZIF connector (or at least I think that's what it is).  Here's me trying to disconnect it:

[image]

As you can see, I have been able to slide the 2 brown things at the end towards the cable, but then I tried to lift the white cover (see photo) and even push the white cover towards the cable, but neither is working.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: The white part might not always move / lift. After puling out the brown tabs, carefully slide the ribbon. I believe it it just held in by the pressure of the tab.

Comment: Absolutely right, Mark!  Couldn't find this anywhere else on the web.  Thank you!!!  P.S. Is this a type of ZIF connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Zero Insertion Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_insertion_force), or ZIF connectors, come in all sorts of shapes and sizes - yes, this is one.

Not even all of them will even have a clip that lifts. The one that you have here has that brown sliding tab, the tab is slightly angled internally so that when pushed in, it provides an upward / downward force on the cable and connector, holding it in place.

After pulling the brown tab out until it contacts its stops you should be able to just gently remove the cable.

To reinstall, stick it in but do not force it (zero insertion force), and then just push the brown tab back in.

Comment: I have no idea where you got Mark from... But you're welcome! - Matt

Comment: Sorry Matt - that's not good.  I think my brain must have optimised your name: MAtt + claRK = MA+RK = Mark.  Hopefully not a new habit.  Can you tell I'm a member of DNA (the National Dyslexia Association)?